User UUID is not set in GeoTools
I have the table with UUID key and want use for them UUID 7 version that have two good thing - sequentiality and storing creating record datetime
There are three way for it - use key from database, set default UUID generation in geoserver and use parameter idgen for wfs-t insert transaction First variant do not implements in geoserver, second also. Last variant is good choice, but not working when I try to call it from my app use geotools library
It is not clear how to set the user identifier. Setting the parameter idgen="UseExisting" is possible only in objects of the InsertElementTypeImpl type.
feature.getUserData().put(Hints.USE_PROVIDED_FID, Boolean.TRUE); - does not work
This was achieved only by overriding the Strategy createInsert method and adding the line insert.setIdgen(IdentifierGenerationOptionType.USE_EXISTING_LITERAL):
protected InsertElementType createInsert(WfsFactory factory, TransactionRequest.Insert elem) throws Exception {
    InsertElementType insert = factory.createInsertElementType();

    insert.setIdgen(IdentifierGenerationOptionType.USE_EXISTING_LITERAL);

    String srsName = getFeatureTypeInfo(elem.getTypeName()).getDefaultSRS();
    insert.setSrsName(new URI(srsName));

    List<SimpleFeature> features = elem.getFeatures();

    insert.getFeature().addAll(features);

    return insert;
}

You can view the code and run the test:  GITHUB
